# $\limsup$ and $\liminf$ of real-valued function (Exercise 9.3.4 in Analysis by Tao )

Tags: real-analysis

Exercise 9.3.4. Propose a definition for limit superior $\limsup_{x \to x_0; x \in E} f(x)$ and $\liminf_{x \to x_0; x\in E} f(x)$, and then propose an analogue of Proposition 9.3.9 for your definition. (For an additional challenge: prove that analogue.)

Proposition 9.3.9. Let $X$ be a subset of $\mathbb{R}$, let $f : X \to \mathbb{R}$ be a function, let $E$ be a subset of $X$, let $x_0$ be an adherent point of $E$, and let $L$ be a real number. Then the following two statements are logically equivalent:

(a) $f$ converges to $L$ at $x_0$ in $E$.

(b) For every sequence $(a_n)_{n=0}^\infty$ which consists entirely of elements of $E$ and converges to $x_0$, the sequence $(f(a_n))_{n=0}^\infty$ converges to $L$.

Attempt: $\limsup_{x \to x_0; x \in E} f(x) = \lim_{\delta \to 0} \sup \{f(x): \text{$x \in E$ s.t. $|x- x_0| < \delta$}\}$. Similarly, $\liminf_{x \to x_0; x \in E} f(x) = \lim_{\delta \to 0} \inf \{f(x): \text{$x \in E$ s.t. $|x- x_0| < \delta$}\}$. Is this correct? Then, what is the analogue of Proposition 9.3.9?

Answer (score 1):

As you can see on the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_superior_and_limit_inferior#Functions_from_metric_spaces_to_complete_lattices), just as in the case of limits, you have to disregard the value at $x_0$ itself, so use $0 < |x-x_0| < \delta$ to exclude it. This is for both definitions, of course.

For 9.3.9. analogues, try:

Equivalent are

1. $\limsup_{x \to x_0; x \in E} f(x)=L$.
2. There exists a sequence $(x_n)$ with all $x_n \in E$ and $x_n \neq x_0$, such that $\lim_{n \to \infty} f(x_n)=L$, and for all such sequences $(y_n)$ , $\lim_{n \to \infty} f(y_n) \le L$ if that limit exists.

I think you should be able to show that. What would the analogue for $\liminf$ be?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It is hard to convince myself that this is the analogue of proposition 9.3.9. Could you explain why 2 in your answer is analogous to (b) in proposition 9.3.9?

Comment: @shk910 if you want a characterisation of limsup by sequences you cannot consider just one sequence. But limsup and liminf are the max and min you can get from limits of $f(x_n)$.

Answer (score 1):

The purpose of Proposition 9.3.9 is to convert limits of continuous functions to limits of sequences (so we can reuse all our propositions of the latter).

Your attempt uses $\lim_{\delta \to 0} \sup \{f(x): \text{$x \in E$ s.t. $|x- x_0| < \delta$}\}$. This is of the form $\lim_{x \to 0} g(x)$ where $x \in \mathbb{R}$, so it is a limit of a continuous function, and as a result, it won't help us reformulate limits of functions as limits of sequences.

My suggestion:

First, set the scene exactly like Proposition 9.3.9 and Definition 9.3.6 do. Copied directly:

> Let $X$ be a subset of $\mathbb{R}$, let $f : X \to \mathbb{R}$ be a function, let $E$ > be a subset of $X$, let $x_0$ be an adherent point of $E$, and let $L$ be a real number.

### Define $\limsup_{x \to x_0; x \in E}f(x)$ and $\liminf_{x \to x_0; x \in E}f(x)$

Define the set $A_{\delta} = \{f(k) : k \in E, |x_0 - k| < \delta\}$ (chosen to match Definition 9.3.3).
Let $n > 1$ be an integer, and define $ S_n:= \sup(A_{\frac{1}{n}})$ and $I_n := \inf(A_{\frac{1}{n}})$ to be the supremum of $A_{\delta}$ and infimum of $A_{\delta}$ respectively for when $\delta = \frac{1}{n}$.

Consider the **sequence** of supremums $S_1, S_2, S_3, ...$ = $(S_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$. If convergent, this sequence will have a limit as per Definition 6.1.8. Make the definition:

$$\limsup_{x\to x_0; x\in E}f(x) := \lim_{n \to \infty} S_n$$

Similarly, consider the sequence $I_1, I_2, I_3,... = (I_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ and make the definition:

$$\liminf_{x\to x_0; x\in E}f(x) := \lim_{n \to \infty} I_n$$

Finally, we are in a position to propose an analogy to Proposition 9.3.9.

### Analogous Proposition

The following two statements are logically equivalent:

- $f$ convergest to $L$ at $x_0$ in $E$.
- $\limsup_{x\to x_0; x\in E}f(x)$ and $\liminf_{x\to x_0; x\in E}f(x)$ both exist and are equal to $L$.

*Note: the construction of $\limsup$ and $\liminf$ makes the proof of this proposition smooth as they both relate closely to the definition of local ε-closeness.*

Comment: Why didn't you take the infimum of the supremums $S_n$, to define the limit superior? I think that limit superior must be defined regardless of convergence, isn't it?

Comment: I think you are right, since $A_{1/n+1}\subseteq A_{1/n}$ so $S_{n+1}\leq S_n$, since the sequence $S_n$ is bounded below by $f(x_0)$ and decreasing, then from Proposition 6.3.8(monotone convergence theorem), the sequence converges to its infimum. Is my justification correct? If yes, how can I find a lower bound when $x_0$ is not in $X$.